# Trouble understanding the perpose of "BindingResult & UriComponentsBuilder"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am having trouble with this part of Controller file, although I did google search but I did not found any satisfactory answer, can anyone help me understand this.

I want to know the use of "BindingResult & UriComponentsBuilder", what is the purpose of using these.

Also, what

```
  public ResponseEntity<MyDataObject> create(@RequestBody @Valid MyDataObject mdo, BindingResult result, UriComponentsBuilder builder, @ModelAttribute("serviceRequest") ServiceRequest sreq) {
        sreq.addRequestData(mdo);
        ServiceResponse response = ts.add(sreq);
        MyDataObject updtQ = getResultBO(response, MyDataObject.class);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(builder.path("/tools/todos/{id}").buildAndExpand(updtQ.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<TodoCDO>(updtQ, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*BindingResult* complements the *@Valid* annotation by storing the results of binding. That is the key takeaway, what it means in practice is that when the request is made, binding occurs, the process in which the values from request parameters or request body is converted and bound to appropriate properties of some java object. Binding is error prone, if the request value cannot be converted to a java type or it doesn't satisfy a validation constraint e.g. *@NotNull*. In this case a *BindingError* occurs.

Without exposing the *BindingResult* you wouldn't know whether a binding error happen, nor would you know the details of it, the response would be `400 bad request` and the request would not enter the method. With the BindingResult set to immediately follow the argument annotated with *@Valid*, the request would enter the handler method, and you would always be able to check if there was any binding errors simply by calling `result.hasErrors` and apply your logic accordingly. Moreover, if you were to add a *Model* instance to the argument list, *BindingResult* object would be added to the model and become available to your view and you would be able to post appropriate message to the users.

For what concerns *UriComponentsBuilder* its a utility class that gives a set of convience method that assist in handling URLs, like in your case, expanding PATH variables, getting variuous URL parts, enconding parameters, the list goes on, but the bottom line is that its a helper class that takes away the pain of doing plain String operations when manipulating URLs.

Comment: @FluffmeisterGeneral But, how i am a new comer for Stackoverflow. Can you tell me please?